# C# - String to list used in Linq Where Any statement

Tags: c#, hyperlink

I would like to use this string as a filter to remove some Ids in a linq query

```
public class ProductKitMakerDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TitleShort { get; set; }
    public string Media { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult KitItemSelect(string culture)
{
    string productMakerIds = "4174,2196,2201,2460,2508,2204";

    //create a list
    var productMakerList = new List<ProductKitMakerDto>();
    foreach (int i in productMakerIds)
    {
        productMakerList.Add(new ProductKitMakerDto { Id = i });
    }

    var itemselects = (from p in _context.Products
                   where p.Matrix == 2400
                   select new ProductKitMakerDto()
                   {
                   Id = p.Id,
                   TitleShort = culture == "de" ? p.TitleShortDe :
                                culture == "fr" ? p.TitleShortFr :
                                p.TitleShortEn,
                    Media = "/img/" + p.Photo,
                    }).ToList();

    //From this query I get 40 results.
    //Then I want to remove the ones from the list:

    //itemselects = itemselects.Where(i => !productMakerList.Any(pml =>pml.Id == i.Id));

    //1st (above) I get an Error CS0266 asking for explicit cast. So aplly the modification

    itemselects = (List<ProductKitMakerDto>)itemselects.Where(i => !productMakerList.Any(pml =>pml.Id == i.Id));

    return Json(itemselects, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I get 500 (Internal Server Error) - xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null );
I guess the list is empty.
Any idea? Thanks

Comment: one of prodoction mark id is 4174 ?? or 4

Comment: @behroozbc 4174! They have a coma separator.

Comment: `foreach (int i in productMakerIds)` is not going to work. You need to [Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0) your `productMakerIds` and parse the individual strings into integers.

Comment: @Filburt: I tried var productMakerList = ProductMakerIds.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList(); And var productMakerList = ProductMakerIds.Split(',').ToList().Select(int.Parse).ToList(); AND then itemselects = itemselects.Where(i => !productMakerList.Contains(i.Id)); but I get error:  type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable in System.Collections.Generic.List

Comment: _"asking for explicit cast"_ `Enumerable.Where` does not return a list so it's pointless to cast it to one, instead append `ToList` after the `Where`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: @Philippe: I've made it an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. this does not work

   ```
   string productMakerIds = "4174,2196,2201,2460,2508,2204";
   var productMakerList = new List<ProductKitMakerDto>();
   foreach (int i in productMakerIds)
   {
       productMakerList.Add(new ProductKitMakerDto { Id = i });
   }
   ```

because you need to split on comma first and parse the `string` to `int`:

```
   foreach (string i in productMakerIds.Split(',')) // and parse i to int with int.Parse
```

2. but since it's a string literal, initialize it correctly in the first place. Don't use a `List<ProductKitMakerDto>` because you just need a `List<int>`, then you can use `Contains`:

   ```
   var productMakerList = new List<int>
   {
       4174, 2196, 2201, 2460, 2508 , 2204
   };
   ```
3. you can not cast to a list if it's not a list and `Enumerable.Where` does not return one:

   ```
   itemselects = (List<ProductKitMakerDto>)itemselects.Where(i => !productMakerList.Any(pml =>pml.Id == i.Id));
   ```

you need to append `ToList` after the `Where`

```
   itemselects = itemselects
       .Where(i => !productMakerList.Any(pml =>pml.Id == i.Id))
       .ToList();
```

but as mentioned, you could also use this `Where` before you create that list the first time, so include the condition witha `Contains` which should be supported:

```
var itemselects = (from p in _context.Products
                   where p.Matrix == 2400
                   && !productMakerList.Contains(p.Id)
                   select new ProductKitMakerDto()
                   {
                      Id = p.Id,
                      TitleShort = culture == "de" 
                         ? p.TitleShortDe 
                         : culture == "fr" ? p.TitleShortFr : p.TitleShortEn,
                      Media = "/img/" + p.Photo,
                   }).ToList();
```

Comment: Curiously this works perfectly: itemselects = itemselects.Where(i => !productMakerList.Any(pml =>pml.Id == i.Id)).ToList();
And your last suggestion with the Where clause before gives me a 500 error

Comment: @Philippe: I have edited my answer. Don't create a `List<ProductKitMakerDto>` but a `List<int>` and use that for `Contains`, that should be supported by your LINQ provider.

Comment: The Linq support it good if I fill the list as you describe. My probleme is I get this list from a string from the Json post. So I have to split and parse. Can I do this without the model?

Comment: @Philippe yes you can. var productMakerIdList=productMakerIds.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList();

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (string i in productMakerIds.Split(','))
    {
        productMakerList.Add(new ProductKitMakerDto { Id = int.Parse(i) });
    }
```

Comment: This solution looks good to me but I get an 500 error xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null )

Comment: by adding ToList() as suggested by TimSchmelter it works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: @Philippe Do yourself a favor and learn how to debug by setting a breakpoint in your backend code instead of wondering about frontend error messages. It's not always as obvious as in this case and an 500 Internal Server Error is no usefull debugging info when posting here.

Comment: @Filburt Promise, I will ;-)